# Storing double digits as variable

Tags: assembly, input, digits, emu8086

So I have this code for a restaurant order system

```
mov ah,09h          ;      
lea dx,getValueMsg  ; Display get value massege
int 21h             ;

mov ah,01h          ;      
int 21h             ; User input the value
sub al,30h          ;        
mov countChicken,al ;

cmp countChicken,1        ;
jb  errorGetChickenValue  ;
                          ; Checking chicken chop value
cmp countChicken,8        ;
ja  errorGetChickenValue  ;
```

and I learned that I can use `var db 0` to store a value for chicken value, but it can only store a single digit if I remembered correctly.
I need to store a double-digit value, for example, 19. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I learned that I can use `var db 0` to store a value for chicken value, but it can only store a single digit if I remembered correctly

A variable defined as **byte** (`db`) can hold the unsigned numbers from 0 to 255. That's definitely more than a single digit which would range from 0 to 9.

> I need to store a double-digit value, for example, 19. How can I do that?

If you need double-digit values, then you'll have to use the DOS.InputCharacter function 01h twice, and combine the digits into a single number in the range 0 to 99. The first digit that gets inputted is the most significant digit and you must multiply it by 10. The second digit that gets inputted is then added to this:

### Using `mul`, 11 instructions and 23 bytes

```
mov ah, 01h
int 21h        ; -> AL
sub al, 30h
mov bl, 10
mul bl         ; AX = AL * BL
mov bl, al
mov ah, 01h
int 21h        ; -> AL
sub al, 30h
add al, bl
mov countChicken, al
```

### Using `AAD`, 8 instructions and 18 bytes

```
mov ah, 01h
int 21h        ; -> AL
mov bl, al
               ; AH = 01h
int 21h        ; -> AL
mov ah, bl
sub ax, 3030h
aad            ; AX = AH * 10 + AL
mov countChicken, al
```